# How to get Single Object in Controller from List of Objects using Razor View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

This is my Controller:

```
namespace OBBMS.Controllers
{
    public class BDMController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {   
            OBBMS.Models.User objUser = new Models.User();
            objUser.lstUser = DB_Interactions.BDMGetUsers("Pending");
            return View(objUser);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(OBBMS.Models.User objUser)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is View Code:

```
@model OBBMS.Models.User
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutBloodDonationManagement.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "BDM", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "BDM"}))
{
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        @*<th>Post ID</th>*@
        <th>Full Name</th>
        <th>Blood Group</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Contact No</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Post Title</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach(var obj in Model.lstUser)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none!important;">@obj.PostID</td>
            <td>@obj.FullName</td>
            <td>@obj.BloodGroupName</td>
            <td>@obj.EmailAddress</td>
            <td>@obj.ContactNo</td>
            <td>@obj.Address</td>
            <td>@obj.PostTitle</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Approve" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Approved" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" /></td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody></table>}
```

I have a submit button at the end of each row, I need to get Single instance of User object instead of complete list in HttpPost ActionResult Method when a specific row button is click. I just need to get the object only the row button is clicked.

**If possible:**
I do not want to use any JavaScript/jQuery/Ajax, everything should be done in APS.NET MVC framework.

**If not possible:**
Suggest me best and easiest way to do it.

Comment: You do not have a `<form>` and you do not have any form controls so there is nothing to submit. Are you wanting to update the status (to approved) of an record in your collection?

Comment: I think you can add a `<form>` tag inside `<td>` tag targeting your `Edit` action in your _submit button_ setting your **user-id** as key parameter to send. Then manage it in your `Edit` action.

Comment: you can make separate form per td and using hidden field you can make it work.

Comment: now I added form tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the [HTML 5 form attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp). The attribute can be used to indicate which form an element belongs to. For example:

```html
  @foreach(var obj in Model.lstUser)
  {
      <tr>
         <td><form id="@("form"+obj.PostID)"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="@obj.PostID" /></form></td>
         <td><input form="@("form"+obj.PostID)" type="text" name="FullName" value="@obj.FullName" /></td>
         <td><input form="@("form"+obj.PostID)" type="text" name="BloodGroupName" value="@obj.BloodGroupName" /></td>
        <-- more td elements here -->
        <td><input form="@("form"+obj.PostID)" type="submit" value="Approve" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Approved" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" /></td>
      </tr>
  }
```

Check [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=form%20attribute) for a list of supported browsers.

Comment: it works in many situations for me